# git - setting path variable

Tags: git, bash, git-tfs

When I run the following command to change my path variable in the git bash - it works.

After I've run a few git-tfs commands it reverts back to the original setup.

Is it possible to explain why?

$ PATH=$PATH:*my git-tfs path goes here*

To clarify, it works at first. But then the git-tfs commands stop working and it's because the folder it lives in no longer appears in the path.

EDIT: When I close the bash the changes are not saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it your `.bash_profile` so that it will be saved. So the contents will be something like:

```
PATH=$PATH:my git-tfs path goes here
export PATH
```