# Installing easy_install with setup tools

Tags: python, setuptools, scrapy

I'm trying to install easy_install using setup tools for the purpose of installing scrapy on Windows XP. On the setup tools page it says:

> Once installation is complete, you will find an easy_install.exe
>   program in your Python Scripts subdirectory. Be sure to add this
>   directory to your PATH environment variable, if you haven't already
>   done so.

But when i install I only find an `easy_install.exe.manifest` file, and I'm not able to run this file. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this. I'm not quite sure what this sentence means either:

> Be sure to add this directory to your PATH environment variable, if
>   you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you should have the path to the directory containing the file when you do

```
echo %PATH% (windows)
echo $PATH (linux/cygwin/...)
```

in the command line. If it does not appear, you should add it.

To do so check out the following links

- [git - setting path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488329/git-setting-path-variable) (linux)
- [How to set ANT_HOME with Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290243/how-to-set-ant-home/9290431#9290431) (windows)